# Seasonal Decomposition plots won't show despite pandas recognizing DateTime Index

Tags: pandas, datetime, time-series, frequency

I loaded the data as follows

```
og_data=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\hp\Downloads\dataframe.xlsx',index_col='DateTime')
```

And it looks like this:

```
DateTime             A
2019-02-04 10:37:54  0
2019-02-04 10:47:54  1
2019-02-04 10:57:54  2
2019-02-04 11:07:54  3
2019-02-04 11:17:54  4
```

Problem is, I'm trying to set the data to a frequency, but there are NaN values that I have to drop, and even if I don't, it seems to be an irregular frequency. I've got pandas to recognize the DateTime to the index:

```
og_data.index

DatetimeIndex
dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='DateTime', length=15536, freq=None)
```

but when I try doing this:

```
og_data.index.freq = '10T'
```

That should mean 10min, right?
But I get the following error instead:

```
ValueError: Inferred frequency None from passed values does not conform to passed frequency 10T
```

Even if I set the frequency to days:

```
og_data.index.freq = 'D'
```

I get a similar error.

The goal is to get a seasonal decomposition plots because I want to forecast the data. But I get the following error when I try to do so:

```
result=seasonal_decompose(og_data['A'],model='add')
result.plot();

ValueError: You must specify a period or x must be a pandas object with a DatetimeIndex with a freq not set to None
```

Which makes sense, I can't set the datetime index to a specified frequency. I need it to be every 10min, please advise.

Comment: do you want to [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) your `df`?

Comment: @MrFuppes I'm willing to resample it to 30min, and I tried that to work, but then I realized I needed to slice the data. I used df.asfreq('30T').index after slicing the data, and it seems that pandas recognizes the frequency as 30min, but I still get the same error when trying to do a seasonal decomposition.